# Filing an ST into the GemStone server with Gem Tools

Tags: smalltalk, pharo, seaside, gemstone

```
1) I have the GemStone server running.
2) I have a Pharo 1.0 image with the gemStone Tools loaded.
3) I could succesfully login to the server after creating a session.
```

Now I have an `"abc.st"` file done by me in another `Pharo-Image`.

I couldn't find any interface which  helps me to  `filein` this ST into the `gemStone` server with the `gemStone` Tool.

Am I missing something?

Comment: As a small note, Pharo 1.0 is quite old, current stable version is 1.4.

Comment: While that is correct ... GemTools (so far) requires an older version of Pharo, since it does not run correctly on newer versions of Pharo ... Pharo 1.1.1 seems to be the latest version of Pharo that works with GemTools ... part of the problem is an FFI bug in the vms (a bug has been submitted ... a while ago) and the other part of the problem is that OmniBrowser has changed significantly enough to require some major rework to get GemTools to work correctly ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The preferred mechanism for transferring code to GemStone using GemTools is to use Monticello packages. If you are unfamiliar with using Monticello, read the [Pharo By Example Monticello chapter](https://gforge.inria.fr/frs/download.php/27018/Monticello.pdf)(pdf). The basic principles described there can be applied to both Pharo and GemStone.

With that said, you can file in a .st file by doing the following:

```
(BinaryOrTextFile openReadOnServer: 'full path to abc.st') 
  fileIn;
  close.
```

Dale